# Replacing the pattern in the code and generating many variants in r

Tags: r, design-patterns, replace, variants

I have the following lines of code.

```
path="http:///XXXX"
a1=as.data.frame(csv[[1]][1][[1]]);a1$group="XXXX"
```

Also I have the names of the 1600 groups for example

```
df=c("ABC0","ABCF", .... "ZZZZ")
```

(There is no pattern in the names of the groups)

I would like to generate the 1,600 sets of the codes in R using "df".
For example,

```
path1="http:///ABC0"
a1=as.data.frame(csv[[1]][1][[1]]);a1$group="ABC0"

path2="http:///ABCF"
a2=as.data.frame(csv[[1]][1][[1]]);a2$group="ABCF"

path3="http:///ZZZZ"
a3=as.data.frame(csv[[1]][1][[1]]);a3$group="ZZZZ"
```

Comment: It is not clear from your example.  Where is the `path` used?  Also, the 'a1' object is replace at each run with new 'group'

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I would like to generate 1,600 lines of codes that look like the "edited" codes. How "path" are used or how "groups" are defined is not important in this question. I simply would like to replace XXX with 1600 names of groups that I have in data frame "df".